# How to add several labels to the same set of data in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm making a simple dashboard which has a bar chart showing the amount of orders for a company.
It shows the quantity ordered each day for the past week, the amount for today, and the amount of scheduled orders for the next days.

I am using colors to set apart each of these 3 moments, but I cannot find a solution to have 3 labels, each one with the right color (blue for 'last week', orange for 'today', and gray for 'scheduled').

[link for current bar chart, as I still don't have enough points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNzV4.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`generateLabels`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) function for this:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: ['lightblue', 'lightblue', 'lightblue', 'orange', 'orange', 'gray']
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          generateLabels: () => {
            return [{
                datasetIndex: 0, // Since its all 1 dataset just hide if it gets clicked, remove this line for legend click to do nothing
                text: 'Last week',
                fillStyle: 'lightBlue',
                strokeStyle: 'lightBlue'
              },
              {
                datasetIndex: 0, // Since its all 1 dataset just hide if it gets clicked, remove this line for legend click to do nothing
                text: 'Today',
                fillStyle: 'orange',
                strokeStyle: 'orange'
              },
              {
                datasetIndex: 0, // Since its all 1 dataset just hide if it gets clicked, remove this line for legend click to do nothing
                text: 'Scheduled',
                fillStyle: 'grey',
                strokeStyle: 'grey'
              }
            ];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It worked as I needed, thank you very much. I did have issues when clicking on the legends, so I just added a `onClick: null` .

Comment: If it solved your issue can you [mark it as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)